# Select checkboxes from JSON

Tags: arrays, json, jsfiddle, checkboxlist

I'm trying to get the selected check boxes from my JSON array but it only returns the checkbox with value="1";  What am I missing?

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/geegirls3/acx1yLex/

```
  <div id="checkboxes">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qcol2" value="1" > Sarah
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="qcol2" value="9" > Sundae
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="qcol2" value="10" > Summer
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="qcol2"  value="11" > GeeZee
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="qcol2"  value="12" > Husband
      <br />
    </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 var initValues = [{my_id: "10"}, {my_id: "11"}, {my_id: "12" }];
 var myjson = JSON.stringify(initValues);
 //alert(myjson);

 $('#checkboxes').find(':checkbox[name^="qcol2"]').each(function() {
   $(this).prop("checked", ($.inArray($(this).val(), myjson) != -1));
   //alert(myjson);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` converts the `initValues` map into a long string, not into an array that you can use `inArray()` with.

If you want to select the checkboxes from a JSON string, you must first parse it, prepare an array with the id values, then you can use `inArray` to select the checkboxes.

check this code:

```
   var myjson = JSON.stringify(initValues);
   var parsed = JSON.parse(myjson);

   var myarray = [];
   $.each(parsed,function(key, value) 
   {
     myarray.push(value["my_id"]);
   });

   $('#checkboxes').find(':checkbox[name^="qcol2"]').each(function() {
       $(this).prop("checked", ($.inArray($(this).val(), myarray) != -1));
       //alert(myjson);
   });
```

Comment: It worked thank you.  I changed my code a little based on your help.   My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/geegirls3/70jd4nv8/